# Por que sale este error ? 'create' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8, fetch, fullcalendar

**       No me toma la funcion create  en js,'create' is declared but its value is never read.ya intente de todo, pero no hayo el error, espero puedan ayudarme, es para la creacion de un full calendar, esa función es para el registro en la base de datos**

```
import { ModelKardex } from './KardexModel.js';
import { Calendario } from './calendario.js'
var calendario = new Calendario();
calendario.main();
function create() {

    event.preventDefault()
    const formData = new ModelKardex()

    const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;

       fetch('/administrador/calendar-set-data',{
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            texto: e.target.value

        }),
       })

       var datos = formData.getAllData()

       fetchResponse(url, 'POST', datos)
       formData.clearInput()
       formData.resetColorInput

()}
```

Comment: ¿Y llave de cierre de la función `create`?

Comment: se me paso, perdona

Comment: Pues eso. No se ve que uses `create`. O es que otro script la usa? o dónde?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.